# How to redirect Python's logging output to Kivy label?

Tags: python, stream, event-handling, output, kivy

As written in the title , i need to redirect the logging module output to a Kivy label in the simple way possible. I searched for a solution on the web an i think the best methods are to overwrite the *StreamHandler* or the *MemoryHandler* in some way (but i don't know how to do this point).

Someone can help me to achieve this?

I use python 2.7

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always make my own logging.Handler for cases like these.

Here is a **working** example:

main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import logging
import thread
import time

def my_thread(log):

    for i in range(2**20):
        time.sleep(1)
        log.info("WOO %s", i)

class MyLabelHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, label, level=logging.NOTSET):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level=level)
        self.label = label

    def emit(self, record):
        "using the Clock module for thread safety with kivy's main loop"
        def f(dt=None):
            self.label.text = self.format(record) #"use += to append..."
        Clock.schedule_once(f)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(text="showing the log here")

        log = logging.getLogger("my.logger")
        log.level = logging.DEBUG
        log.addHandler(MyLabelHandler(label, logging.DEBUG))

        thread.start_new(my_thread, (log,))

        return label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Notice the simple thread here to test the logging.

Comment: Good solution. Let me ask 2 questions on it: isn't better the StreamHandler instead of basic Handler? and you really need to use both the schedule function and the thread instance? From what I know (if I'm not mistaken) the Kivy Clock class is implemented using threads.

Comment: @Tungsteno     I'm not sure its better, just different. The kivy Clock is **not implmented** using threads, it just schedule an event the kivy main gui thread. calling other methods of kivy except Clock is considered unsafe.

Comment: Excellent canonical answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can write log to a file, and read it with your app in a separate thread. Without separate thread, GUI will be frozen.

test.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

GridLayout:
    cols: 1

    LogButton:
        text: 'log me'
        on_press: self.log_me()

    ScrollView:

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

            LogLabel:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
                halign: 'center'
```

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import logging
import threading
import time


class LogButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.set_logger()

    def set_logger(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('example')
        hdlr = logging.FileHandler('example.log')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
        )
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(hdlr)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def log_me(self, *x):
        self.logger.debug('logger text')


class LogLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_log)
        thread.daemon = True  # kill thread on app close
        thread.start()

    def read_log(self):
        with open('example.log', 'r') as file:
            while 1:
                where = file.tell()
                line = file.readline()
                if not line:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    file.seek(where)
                else:
                    # newest logs on top
                    self.text = '%s%s' % (line, self.text)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return self.root


Test().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think this solution isn't very elegant and is IO intensive (on HDD).

Comment: actually it is not so bad solution. when you ready to read logs it is not intensive and you usually need to save them too. this I what I looked for.