# Redirect / Copy python & kivy's logging onto a text input

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

In a part of an app I am developing, I would like to able the user view the **logger that python & kivy output** to see any sort of warnings or issues that may have been caused.

I searched this and there way only one stackoverflow issue regarding this: [so issue on redirecting python logging onto a kivy label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539563/how-to-redirect-pythons-logging-output-to-kivy-label)

I tried the exact same code (the one checked as an answer) but all I got was a label that said ***WOO %*** and a timer as its last character.

I had an idea which was to access **the log record that kivy writes to** but practically it won't work because for how long should I access the file? Should I create a `while True: read_file()` loop and put it in another thread and run it forever? Ultimately, it was not a good ides.

If this is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
TextInput:
    # redirect (preferably copy) logger text here
    id: logger_text
    readonly: True
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

How can I redirect (but preferably copy) this logger onto my text input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concepts from the so question that you cited. Here is a modified version of that so answer employing your kivy code:

```
import logging

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyLabelHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, label, level=logging.NOTSET):
        super(MyLabelHandler, self).__init__(level=level)
        self.label = label

    def emit(self, record):
        "using the Clock module for thread safety with kivy's main loop"
        def f(dt=None):
            self.label.text += self.format(record) + '\n' #"use += to append..."
        Clock.schedule_once(f)


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:  # added because `id` on root object has no effect
    TextInput:
        # redirect (preferably copy) logger text here
        id: logger_text
        readonly: True
''')

    def build(self):
        # use Kivy Logger
        Logger.level = logging.INFO
        Logger.addHandler(MyLabelHandler(self.kv.ids.logger_text, logging.INFO))

        # send some logging from this app
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.send_log, 2)

        return self.kv

    def send_log(self, dt):
        #  This is just to demonstrate some logging fom this App
        Logger.info('MyApp: this is a test at ' + str(dt) + ' seconds')
        logging.info('this is a python log')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```